# What is the difference between viewableID and guid?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

In forge viewer, for a revit converted file, when making a bubble search:
viewerApp.bubble.search({ 'type': 'geometry', 'role': '3d' });
Or
viewerApp.getSelectedItem()

I get an element node like:

```
children: (2) [a, a]
data: {guid: "a21582db-704b-df51-dd71-dbf8c12bcc1a", type: "geometry", role: "3d", name: "{3D}", viewableID: "6104055e-60d9-4037-9adc-cd38e10fcfba-00139c8e", …}
id: 8
isLeaf: true
parent: a {parent: a, id: 7, data: {…}, isLeaf: false, children: Array(14)}
```

I have the *guid* of the node, and a *viewableID*.
Then, to display a model, I can call viewerApp.selectItemById(guid/viewableID), which ends displaying the same model.

If I want to point to the 3D view I currently see in the viewer, for future reference (e.g. after revit file update), what is the best attribute for it, guid or viewableID?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The viewable id stands for the unique id of the Revit views in Revit API as my research, but I cannot find the relationship between Revit views and guid in the viewable bubble node. I'm checking with our engineering team if they have some insights.

The `viewerApp.selectItemById()` is for querying bubble node via its' guid, so you cannot pass viewable id into it. Otherwise, it will return nothing as my investigation.

To archive selecting by viewable id, I would advise you to use the follow instead:

```
const bubbles = viewerApp.bubble.search({ 'viewableID': '6104055e-60d9-4037-9adc-cd38e10fcfba-00139c8e' });

viewerApp.selectItemById( bubbles[0].guid );
```

Or extend your own methods (tested with v6.2):

```
LMV.BubbleNode.prototype.findByViewableId = function (viewableId) {
    let item = null;

    this.traverse(function (node) {
        if (node.data.viewableID === viewableId) {
            item = node;
            return true;
        }
    });

    return item;
};

LMV.ViewingApplication.prototype.selectItemViewableId = function (viewableId, onItemSelectedCallback, onItemFailedToSelectCallback) {
    let item = this.myDocument.getRoot().findByViewableId(viewableId);
    if (item) {
        return this.selectItem(item, onItemSelectedCallback, onItemFailedToSelectCallback);
    }
    return false;
};

// -- You codes where you create the ViewingApplication instance
```